# Using SED command to get values from absolute path

Tags: shell, unix

I'm new to shell scripting. I need to get the value "test" from the below absolute path and print it. How can this be achieved using SED command. Please help.

/home/path/test_script/logs

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion **awk** performs better this task. Using -F you can use multiple delimiters such as "/" and "_":

```
echo /home/path/test_script/logs | awk -F'/|_' '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try awk command:

```
echo /home/path/test_script/logs | awk -F"/" '{print $4}' | cut -c1-4
```

Your output should be 'test'.
You can also assign the 'test' value to a variable by doing the below:

```
var1=`echo /home/path/test_script/logs | awk -F"/" '{print $4}' | cut -c1-4`
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` code to first remove the `_` and what's to the *right* of it, then the `/`s and what's to the *left* of those, leaving only *"test"*.

```
echo /home/path/test_script/logs | sed 's/[_].*//;s,.*/,,g'
```

Output:

```
test
```